# Why is my menu button activating across the screen?

Tags: html, css

I recently created a website with a dropdown menu on the left side. However, whenever I'm at the top of the screen, where the dropdown would be on the left, the dropdown activates even when I'm on the other side of the screen. I was expecting it to only activate when I hover over the button itself.

```css
   .dropbtn {
  background-color: rgb(191, 255, 181);
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 45px;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #98CC90;
  min-width: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.dropdown {
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #182016;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #79A373;}

.dropdown-content a:hover {border-radius: 5px;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: rgb(191, 255, 181);}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"><div class="menu"><img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/thumbs/menu-icon/menu-icon-6.png"/></div></button>
  
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a onclick="window.location.href='https://ieatlargefrogs.com/about-me.html';">About me</a>
    <a onclick="window.location.href='https://ieatlargefrogs.com/dnilist.html';">DNI List</a>
    <a onclick="window.location.href='https://ieatlargefrogs.com/website.html';">Website Stuff</a>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned in the question, you want the `dropdown-content` to be displayed only when the button is hovered. But for hovering the `dropdown-content`, it has to remain displayed even when `dropdown-content` is  hovered.
So I have modified your code.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: rgb(191, 255, 181);
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 45px;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #98CC90;
  min-width: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.dropdown {
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #182016;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #79A373;}

.dropdown-content a:hover {border-radius: 5px;}

.dropbtn:hover + .dropdown-content, .dropdown-content:hover {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: rgb(191, 255, 181);}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"><div class="menu"><img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/thumbs/menu-icon/menu-icon-6.png"/></div></button>
  
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a onclick="window.location.href='https://ieatlargefrogs.com/about-me.html';">About me</a>
    <a onclick="window.location.href='https://ieatlargefrogs.com/dnilist.html';">DNI List</a>
    <a onclick="window.location.href='https://ieatlargefrogs.com/website.html';">Website Stuff</a>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Please ensure that there is always positional continuity between `dropbtn` and `dropdown-content`. Otherwise, it will not be possible to hover the `dropdown-content`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: rgb(191, 255, 181);
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 45px;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #98CC90;
  min-width: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.dropdown {
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #182016;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #79A373;}

.dropdown-content a:hover {border-radius: 5px;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: rgb(191, 255, 181);}
```

try setting the display of the a tags to inline block. The problem is that block display will stretch over the entire width of the container on default.

alternatively you can set a width to the dropdown-content

Comment: .dropdown-content is the buttons in the dropdown. Setting that to inline-block makes the dropdown options horizontal, instead of vertical, and does not fix my issue sadly.